# Check if text fits inside textview

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have a problem. I need to adjust the font size of a text, so it fits inside the TextView. But how can I get the size of the TextView and the size of the Text to compare with each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If android api is above 8 , you can do that easily in *axml*:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="80dp"  //code one
        android:autoSizeMinTextSize="2dp"  // code two
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" // code three
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"  // be sure not return line
        android:text="Here is auto size text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="80dp" />
```

else you can refer to the follow code to custom a *TextView*:

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Text;

using Java.Lang;

namespace My.Text
{
    public class AutoResizeTextView : TextView
    {
        public const float MIN_TEXT_SIZE = 20;

        public interface OnTextResizeListener
        {
            void OnTextResize(TextView textView, float oldSize, float newSize);
        }

        private const string mEllipsis = "...";

        private OnTextResizeListener mTextResizeListener;

        private bool mNeedsResize = false;

        private float mTextSize;

        private float mMaxTextSize = 0;

        private float mMinTextSize = MIN_TEXT_SIZE;

        private float mSpacingMult = 1.0f;

        private float mSpacingAdd = 0.0f;

        public bool AddEllipsis { get; set; } = true;

        public AutoResizeTextView(Context context) : this(context, null) { }

        public AutoResizeTextView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : this(context, attrs, 0) { }

        public AutoResizeTextView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle): base(context, attrs, defStyle)
        {
            mTextSize = TextSize;
        }

        protected override void OnTextChanged(ICharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter)
        {
            base.OnTextChanged(text, start, lengthBefore, lengthAfter);

            mNeedsResize = true;

            ResetTextSize();
        }

        protected override void OnSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
        {
            base.OnSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

            if (w != oldw || h != oldh)
                mNeedsResize = true;
        }

        public void SetOnResizeListener(OnTextResizeListener listener)
        {
            mTextResizeListener = listener;
        }

        public override void SetTextSize([GeneratedEnum] ComplexUnitType unit, float size)
        {
            base.SetTextSize(unit, size);

            mTextSize = TextSize;
        }

        public override void SetLineSpacing(float add, float mult)
        {
            base.SetLineSpacing(add, mult);

            mSpacingMult = mult;
            mSpacingAdd = add;
        }

        public void SetMaxTextSize(float maxTextSize)
        {
            mMaxTextSize = maxTextSize;
            RequestLayout();
            Invalidate();
        }

        public float GetMaxTextSize()
        {
            return mMaxTextSize;
        }

        public void SetMinTextSize(float minTextSize)
        {
            mMinTextSize = minTextSize;
            RequestLayout();
            Invalidate();
        }

        public float GetMinTextSize()
        {
            return mMinTextSize;
        }

        public void ResetTextSize()
        {
            if(mTextSize > 0)
            {
                base.SetTextSize(ComplexUnitType.Px, mTextSize);
                mMaxTextSize = mTextSize;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
        {
            if(changed || mNeedsResize)
            {
                int widthLimit = (right - left) - CompoundPaddingLeft - CompoundPaddingRight;
                int heightLimit = (bottom - top) - CompoundPaddingBottom - CompoundPaddingTop;
                ResizeText(widthLimit, heightLimit);
            }
            base.OnLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

            base.OnLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        }

        public void ResizeText()
        {
            int heightLimit = Height - PaddingBottom - PaddingTop;
            int widthLimit = Width - PaddingLeft - PaddingRight;
            ResizeText(widthLimit, heightLimit);
        }

        public void ResizeText(int width, int height)
        {
            var text = TextFormatted;
            if (text == null || text.Length() == 0 || height <= 0 || width <= 0 || mTextSize == 0)
                return;

            if (TransformationMethod != null)
                text = TransformationMethod.GetTransformationFormatted(TextFormatted, this);

            TextPaint textPaint = Paint;

            float oldTextSize = textPaint.TextSize;
            float targetTextSize = mMaxTextSize > 0 ? System.Math.Min(mTextSize, mMaxTextSize) : mTextSize;

            int textHeight = GetTextHeight(text, textPaint, width, targetTextSize);

            while(textHeight > height && targetTextSize > mMinTextSize)
            {
                targetTextSize = System.Math.Max(targetTextSize - 2, mMinTextSize);
                textHeight = GetTextHeight(text, textPaint, width, targetTextSize);
            }

            if(AddEllipsis && targetTextSize == mMinTextSize && textHeight > height)
            {
                TextPaint paint = new TextPaint(textPaint);

                StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(text, paint, width, Layout.Alignment.AlignNormal, mSpacingMult, mSpacingAdd, false);
                if(layout.LineCount > 0)
                {
                    int lastLine = layout.GetLineForVertical(height) - 1;
                    if (lastLine < 0)
                        SetText("", BufferType.Normal);
                    else
                    {
                        int start = layout.GetLineStart(lastLine);
                        int end = layout.GetLineEnd(lastLine);
                        float lineWidth = layout.GetLineWidth(lastLine);
                        float ellipseWidth = textPaint.MeasureText(mEllipsis);

                        while (width < lineWidth + ellipseWidth)
                            lineWidth = textPaint.MeasureText(text.SubSequence(start, --end + 1).ToString());
                        SetText(text.SubSequence(0, end) + mEllipsis, BufferType.Normal);
                    }
                }
            }

            SetTextSize(ComplexUnitType.Px, targetTextSize);
            SetLineSpacing(mSpacingAdd, mSpacingMult);

            mTextResizeListener?.OnTextResize(this, oldTextSize, targetTextSize);

            mNeedsResize = false;
        }

        private int GetTextHeight(ICharSequence source, TextPaint paint, int width, float textSize)
        {
            TextPaint paintCopy = new TextPaint(paint);
            paintCopy.TextSize = textSize;
            StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(source, paintCopy, width, Layout.Alignment.AlignNormal, mSpacingMult, mSpacingAdd, false);
            return layout.Height;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And is there a way to keep the text in the center. Now when the text gets smaller it moves to the top of the TextView. How can I keep it in the center?

Comment: Can you also take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56439817/set-first-row-to-column-name-and-adjust-column-width?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk Okey, you can have a try with `android:gravity="center"` in *axml*.